# Scroll down method selects text in Appium

Tags: java, automation, appium

I'm using TouchAction with coordinates in Appium to scroll down the native app. Code sample:

```
TouchAction ts = new TouchAction(driver);ts.press(207, 582).moveTo(8, -360).release().perform();
```

But there is a caveat - one section in the app contains a large piece of text. And instead of scrolling down the methods selects the words in the text (like a long press to copy the word) and doesn't scroll.
I've tried setting coordinates to avoid the text during scrolling but no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
        action.press(PointOption.point(startX,startY))
              .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
              .moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY))  
              .release().perform();
```

If you are automating iOS, check out this,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

For more details - [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/)